# Write a number N as a sum of K numbers

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

> I need to find the no of ways of partitioning a number N as a sum of K non-negative numbers.

**Zeroes are also needed to be included in the sum.**

Ordering **does** matter.

*Example-*

> For $N=2,K=3 $
>
> There are $6$ ways **{1,1,0},{1,0,1},{0,1,1},{2,0,0},{0,0,2},{0,2,0}**

I need an efficient recursive relation for this ?

Comment: If ordering matters then this is called *compositions*, not *partitions*, and the formula is pretty straightforward (if memory serves correctly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  Either the first number is zero, and you want $k-1$ numbers adding to $n$, or the first number is not zero.  In the second case, find $k$ numbers that add to $n-1$, then add $1$ to the first number.

So $F(n,k)=F(n,k-1)+F(n-1,k)$
Use that to build up a bunch of values of $F(n,k)$ for, say $n=1..4$, $k=1..4$.

Comment: So there isn't a definitive formula?

Comment: Try it and tell us what you get.

Answer (score 2):

This is the bars and stars problem. Your problem is equivalent to this one:

> How many ways are there to rearrange $N$ stars and $K-1$ bars? Answer: $\binom {N+K-1}{K-1}$

Think in the stars as balls that you have to put in a row of boxes, and think in the bars as the walls between boxes.

Comment: Is it matching with $N=5$ and $K=3$ ... Your formula shows $\dfrac{7!}{2! 5!}=21$...I couldn't get as many...(am i wrong?)

Comment: With two numbers equal: $5+0+0$, $3+1+1$, $1+2+2$. Since there are three permutations for each, this makes $9$ ways. With pairwise different numbers: $0+1+4$, $0+2+3$. Since there are six permutations for each, this makes $12$ ways. $12+9=21$.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense...my bad!